# How can I get a specific thread to be the next one to enter a synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked this in an interview.

> There are four threads t1,t2,t3 and t4. t1 is executing a synchronized block and the other threads are waiting for t1 to complete. What operation would you do, so that t3 executes after t1.

I answered that join method should do the trick, but it looks like it isn't the right answer.The reason he gave was, the join method and the setPriority method would not work on threads that are wait state.

Can we achieve this? If yes, how?

Comment: If t3 is waiting for t1 to complete, it will certainly execute after t1.

Comment: I presume he's asking for an explanation of wait / notify, but the question is so vague it's hard to tell.

Comment: As i understand it all are waiting for t1 and he wants to execute t3 before t2 and t4

Comment: @mibollma : Yes you are right.

Comment: If that really WAS the question, don't work for this company. The question is vague and misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i would use some latches. One countdownlatch between t1 and t2, another one between t2 and t3, the last one between t3 and t4. T1 Ends with countDown, and t2 starts the to be synchronized part with await.

That way all threads can do preprocessing in parallel and restore order for the sequential part.

I can't say it's elegant though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use locks and conditions. Pass same condition to both t1 and t3:

```
class Junk {

   private static class SequencedRunnable implements Runnable {
       private final String name;
       private final Lock sync;
       private final Condition toWaitFor;
       private final Condition toSignalOn;

       public SequencedRunnable(String name, Lock sync, Condition toWaitFor, Condition toSignalOn) {
           this.toWaitFor = toWaitFor;
           this.toSignalOn = toSignalOn;
           this.name = name;
           this.sync = sync;
       }

       public void run() {
           sync.lock();
           try {
               if (toWaitFor != null)
                   try {
                       System.out.println(name +": waiting for event");
                       toWaitFor.await();
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               System.out.println(name + ": doing useful stuff...");
               if (toSignalOn != null)
                   toSignalOn.signalAll();
           } finally {
               sync.unlock();
           }
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
       Condition start = l.newCondition();
       Condition t3AfterT1 = l.newCondition();
       Condition allOthers = l.newCondition();
       Thread t1 = new Thread(new SequencedRunnable("t1", l, start, t3AfterT1));
       Thread t2 = new Thread(new SequencedRunnable("t2", l, allOthers, allOthers));
       Thread t3 = new Thread(new SequencedRunnable("t3", l, t3AfterT1, allOthers));
       Thread t4 = new Thread(new SequencedRunnable("t4", l, allOthers, allOthers));

       t1.start();
       t2.start();
       t3.start();
       t4.start();

       l.lock();
       try {
           start.signalAll();
       } finally {
           l.unlock();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: When I run your code, all threads get into wait state after few iterations, what is the issue?

Comment: @salman.mirghasemi My original post contained wrong set of conditions passed to threads. I've fixed code and believe current code to be correct. If you still get stuck, could you please post output here?

Answer (score 5):

Every thread should simply wait() on a separate object. So t3 should wait on t3Mutex. You could then simply notify that specific thread.

```
final Object t1Mutex = new Object();
final Object t3Mutex = new Object();
...
synchronized(t3Mutex) {
    //let thread3 sleep
    while(condition) t3Mutex.wait();
}
...
synchronized(t1Mutex) {
   //do work, thread1
   synchronized(t3Mutex) {t3Mutex.notify();}
}
```

Comment: If all threads are waiting for t1 to complete, you can just let all threads wait on the same object and use notifyAll().

Comment: @Voo no you can't if you want to ensure that t3 is the one being executed next (and before t2 and t4). Which is I believe the actual question.

Comment: @M Platvoet Yeah the question is diffuse enough to be able to interpret it in all kinds of different ways

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any standard way but i guess i would pass around some kind of token and only the one that has the token is allowed to execute... the others yield(). So t1 would give the token to t3 when it's finished. But maybe there is a better way to do that.

Also this would require to use notifyAll() instead of notify().

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the `notify()` method in the synchronization block of t1.

http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/threads/notify.html

EDIT:

I made a mistake about `notify()` above, it will be at the JVM's discretion, however if t2 and t4 `join()` to to t3 then this method should work.

Comment: Will this make sure that t3 executes and not t2 or t4 ?

Comment: Nope i think it will just wake any of them

Comment: why won't t2 and t4 be notified? As far as I understand, any of t2,t3 or t4 can be notified.\

Comment: You can't be sure t3 will be woken up.

Comment: How do you make sure it's t3? notify: "Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation."

Comment: My bad, I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if T1 has executed we could then use a flag to allow only T3 to run.
Once T3 execution completes then rest of the threads can execute.

Now this may not be an elegant solution.

But from an interview point of view, this will showcase that you understand wait and notifyall.

But again depends on the person who is taking the interview.

```
public class ThreadSequenceTest implements Runnable {
    Object o = new Object();
    volatile boolean t3Only = false;

    public void run() {
        synchronized (o) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t1")) {
                doSomething();
                t3Only = true;
            } else {
                if (t3Only) {
                    if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t3")) {
                        doSomething();
                        t3Only = false;
                        o.notifyAll();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("going to sleep " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            o.wait();
                            doSomething();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    doSomething();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadSequenceTest threadSequenceTest = new ThreadSequenceTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(threadSequenceTest);
        t1.setName("t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(threadSequenceTest);
        t2.setName("t2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(threadSequenceTest);
        t3.setName("t3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(threadSequenceTest);
        t4.setName("t4");

        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

package producer.consumer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadInterComm {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    List<Integer> sharedObject = new ArrayList<Integer>(1);
    sharedObject.add(new Integer(0));

    Runnable task = new MyTask(sharedObject);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(task, "T1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(task, "T2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(task, "T3");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

}
```

}

class MyTask implements Runnable {

```
private final List<Integer> sharedObject;
String name = "T1";//Initializing with T1 

public MyTask(List<Integer> sharedObject) {
    this.sharedObject = sharedObject;
}

public void run() {

    synchronized (sharedObject) {
        while (true) {//Or use a counter how many times to do the job
            if (!name.equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
                try {
                    sharedObject.wait();//Let other Threads wait
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (name.equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
                int value = sharedObject.remove(0).intValue();
                sharedObject.add(new Integer(++value));
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : "
                        + sharedObject.get(0));
                if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T1")) {

                    name = "T2";// give lock to t2
                } else if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T2")) {

                    name = "T3";// give lock to t3
                } else if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T3")) {

                    name = "T1";// give lock to t1
                }
                i--;
                sharedObject.notifyAll();
            }

    }}

}
```

}